# Vue js data value is not changing after assign

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have defined the data like this

```
data() {
    return {
        mdrender: '',
        markdown: ''
    };
},
```

And I have this function :

```
methods: {
    interpretVars: function(markdown) {
        $.getJSON("/api/v1/getdoc?code=" + this.$route.query.code, function (result) {
            var interpreted = markdown.replace(/\{\#(companyName)\#\}/g, 'Demo')
                .replace(/\{\#(docType)\#\}/g, result[0].datas.category).replace(/\{\#(version)\#\}/g, result[0].datas.version)
                .replace(/\{\#(docTitle)\#\}/g, result[0].datas.title);
            this.markdown = interpreted;
          console.log(interpreted);
          return interpreted;
        });
    }
},
```

Now the problem is that the `markdown` data value does not take the new value, while the variable that I'm console logging `interpreted` have the correct value.

I'm doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance for  replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the use of the `function()` statement. So you will loose the scope and `this` doesn't represents to the current Vue instance. There are two possible solutions to fix this:

**Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):**

```
methods: {
  interpretVars: function(markdown) {
    $.getJSON("/api/v1/getdoc?code=" + this.$route.query.code, (result) => {
      …
    });
  }
},
```

**Use a helper variable:**

```
methods: {
  interpretVars: function(markdown) {
    var $this = this;
    $.getJSON("/api/v1/getdoc?code=" + this.$route.query.code, function (result) {
      …
      $this.markdown = interpreted;
    });
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Store `this` scope variable to a temporary variable and use that variable.

```
methods: {
        interpretVars: function(markdown) {
            let that = this;
            $.getJSON("/api/v1/getdoc?code=" + this.$route.query.code, function (result) {
                var interpreted = markdown.replace(/\{\#(companyName)\#\}/g, 'Demo')
                    .replace(/\{\#(docType)\#\}/g, result[0].datas.category).replace(/\{\#(version)\#\}/g, result[0].datas.version)
                    .replace(/\{\#(docTitle)\#\}/g, result[0].datas.title);
                that.markdown = interpreted;
              console.log(interpreted, that.markdown);
              return interpreted;
            });
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way of doing this would be doing it like this :

```
methods: {
 async interpretVars(markdown) {
    $.getJSON("/api/v1/getdoc?code=" + this.$route.query.code, function (result) {
        var interpreted = markdown.replace(/\{\#(companyName)\#\}/g, 'Demo')
            .replace(/\{\#(docType)\#\}/g, result[0].datas.category).replace(/\{\#(version)\#\}/g, result[0].datas.version)
            .replace(/\{\#(docTitle)\#\}/g, result[0].datas.title);

      this.markdown = interpreted;
      console.log(interpreted);
      return interpreted;
    });
}
```

This should work as expected i guess, please don't assign `this` to temp variable.